# Flagging field from wide format

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am working with a df which takes the structure

```
df = data.frame(customer = c(1,2)
                , destination_1 = c("c", "b")
                , destination_2 = c("a", NA)
                )
+----------+----------------+---------------+
| customer |  destination_1 | destination_2 | 
+----------+----------------+---------------+
| 1        | c              | a             |
+----------+----------------+---------------+
| 2        | b              | NA            | 
+----------+----------------+---------------+
```

There is no ordering of destination on a row (nor column) basis. E.g. we see that for customer 1 his destinations are laid out as c, a

I am looking to have n number of columns added to df (where n = number of unique destinations in entire df) as flagging fields to display if each customer has been to each destination.
i.e.

```
df$destination_a <- c(1,0)
df$destination_b <- c(0,1)
df$destination_c <- c(1,0)

+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| customer |  destination_1 | destination_2 | destination_a | destination_b | destination_c |
+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1        | c              | a             | 1             | 0             | 1             |
+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2        | b              | NA            | 0             | 1             | 0             |
+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I only have the slightest idea of how to achieve this. Possibly the use of an apply in a loop? I would much prefer a base R solution if possible. I look forward to hearing any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
# 1) get the number and destination names of required columns by extracting unique values from your dataframe:
df2 <- df[,c(2,3,4,5)]  #subsetting variables containing the destinations (modify column numbers if needed)
all <- c()
for (i in 1:ncol(df2)){for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){all <- c(all, as.character((df2[j,i])))}}
all <- sort(unique(all))

# 2) from these values make column names and columns and fill them with NAs
all_names <- paste("destination_", all, sep="")
df[,all_names] <- NA

# At this point you have the dataframe with required columns, and you can 
# 3) now you can fill these columns with values (0 or 1):

for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
  rowvalues <- c()
  for (k in 1:ncol(df)){rowvalues <- c(rowvalues, as.character((df[j,k])))}

  for (i in 1:length(all)){
    x <- (ncol(df)-length(all))
    if (all[i] %in% rowvalues){val <- 1}
    else {val <- 0}
    df[j, (i+x)] <- val  
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe we are terribly mistaken. I am looking to have the columns 4:6 created and that they flag which destination the customer has been to. Not only to have blank columns created to be filled.
Nonetheless, I appreciate you helping. @Oka

Comment: I am parsing the loops. However, the end table only flags customer 1 has been to one of the destinations where s/he has been to both 'c' and 'a'

Comment: Try it now. I´ve corrected the code and it gives correct results with my toy data.

Comment: thank you. However, I don’t understand this line: df[,c(2,3,4,5)] we start off with the original table which only has 3 columns. As such this produces an error. My goal is to start off with the 1st table (with 3 columns only) and end up with the 2nd table.

Comment: this subsets the dataframe because you don´t want to use your ID column to get the unique destinations. basically this just takes variables 2,3,4 and 5 and make new columns for destinations contained in those variables. You can change the variables as you want by removing/adding the numbers.

Comment: perhaps you need to define subdf

Comment: @T.Fung Sorry, there was a typo. Corrected now.  Does the code work? Do you get correct answer? or does it produce errors?

Comment: Works as needed! Thank you. I have added my little addition
sort(setdiff(unique(all), NA))

btw, do you happen to know a more elegant solution such as one that utilises apply? I am concerned about the solution not scaling well

Comment: Cool! I was thinking about sort at some point but skipped as it wasn´t asked specifically! Good thinking. I´ll add that to the code.

Comment: I think this should work quite well also for larger dataframes as well, but I´ll check if I find something with apply.